# DriveApp root Computers folder

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know how to easily access the Google Drive "Computers" folder that contains entries for each of a user's computers that was synced using the Google "Backup and Sync" application?

I've created a simple app script (more out of interest than anything else) which creates a Google Sheets document listing the contents of the current user's G-Drive.   It starts with a call to DriveApp.getRootFolder(), and then lists and navigates the file tree from there.  This all works fine, but it does not contain anything that is not a child of "My Drive", such as the Backup and Sync files stored under the "Computers" pseudo-root folder.

I've tried using DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Computers"), but that returned an iterator with zero items.

Comment: Have you take a look at this [part of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_folders) ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Pierre-MarieRichard - I had not looked at the advanced services.   However, when I ran the script, it only listed the folders that are children of "My Drive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. You can only touch your regular "My Drive" (or team drive) files. No mention of that in [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

Comment: I've reported this in the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70334122